# Get Values from Dynamically Added Textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I have two tables in my database: `Question` and `Answers`. One question gets 1 or more answers as its nature. I was trying to add answer textboxes dynamically. Users can add as many desired answers as they want. I used panels in divs for this: div1 gets panel1, div2 gets panel2 an so on.

In panels I have TextBoxes which I gave added dynamically and gave their id numeric like txtAnswer1 and txtAnswer2. When I press submit button I would like to turn this txtboxes and get their values but how?

I tried this [link](http://learning2code.net/Learn/2009/8/12/Adding-Controls-to-an-ASPNET-form-Dynamically.aspx) solution but I couldn't do it.

http://learning2code.net/Learn/2009/8/12/Adding-Controls-to-an-ASPNET-form-Dynamically.aspx

This is the design view:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
    </div>
    <div style="border: medium solid #000000;">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAns" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </div>

    <div style="border: medium solid #000099;">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlJ" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <div style="border: medium solid #000000;">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlA" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnGetValues" runat="server" Text="Get Values" OnClick="btnGetValues_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblValues" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This one is the code behind:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(txtCount.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox { ID = "txtAns" + i.ToString() };
        pnlAns.Controls.Add(txt);
        TextBox txtA = new TextBox { ID = "txtPoint" + i.ToString() };
        pnlA.Controls.Add(txtA);
        TextBox txtJ = new TextBox { ID = "txtOther" + i.ToString() };
        pnlJ.Controls.Add(txtJ);
    }
}
```

With my code controls add input.

I would like to get input values in button click.

```
protected void btnGetValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

My question is how?

As you can see I have 3 panels and 3 different textboxes. Thats where I try to find out.

I try to add panels in panel array, But still cant get textboxes values. :(

```
protected void btnGetValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel[] pnls = new Panel[3] { pnlAns, pnlA, pnlJ };

    foreach (Panel pnlIn in pnls)
    {
        lblValues.Text = pnlIn.Controls.ToString();
    }
}
```

i have no idea whats wrong with me but when i press add button i can add textboxes but they are just html textboxes. i mean they are `<input name="txtOther0" type="text" id="txtOther0" />` . and when i try to run your code exception handled and kick me out of the foreach loop. i guess inputs are not have server tag.if this is the problem how can i make them 'runat="server"' ?

do i have to add textboxes values ViewState and if its yes.how?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the values from the TextBoxes that you added dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a panel around your answer textboxes and make sure you have the runat="server" and you know the ID. Then you can look at the controls that are children to that panel and look to see if the control is of type Textbox. If it is then get your answer from the text property.

psuedo code:

```
panel pnl = findpanel("mypanel");
foreach (control ctrl in pnl.controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        //get the text property value here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve values from dynamically added `TextBox` inside a `Panel`, you'll want to loop through all of the `TextBox` controls inside the `Panel` as so:

```
Control answerPanel = Page.FindControl("AnswerPanelID");
foreach( Control childControl in answerPanel.Controls )
{
    if( childControl is TextBox )
    {
        //Retrieve and store value from childControl.Text
    }
}
```

Using this method, you don't have to worry about retrieving the controls by individual ID. If you want to search for a control with a specific ID, use the `Page.FindControl()` method.

With your edited explanation:

The code just needs a little bit of adjusting. You loop through an array of panel controls, which is correct. What's incorrect, is how you're trying to get the values.

```
lblValues.Text = pnlIn.Controls.ToString()
```

won't work. Instead of that, it should be:

```
protected void btnGetValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel[] pnls = new Panel[3] { pnlAns, pnlA, pnlJ };
    ArrayList answers = new ArrayList();
    //Alternatively....
    System.Collections.Hashtable ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

    foreach (Panel pnlIn in pnls)
    {
        foreach( Control childControl in pnlIn.Controls )
        {
            if( childControl is TextBox )
            {
                TextBox box = (TextBox)childControl;
                //Retrieve and store value from childControl.Text
                answers.Add(box.Text);
                //Alternatively...
                ht.Add( box.ID, box.Text );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, you'll have the `ArrayList` (or `HashTable`, indexed by the ID of the `TextBox`) full of values of all text boxes in the panel. If you have both questions and answers in the panel, your if statement will have to check to see if the ID contains "Answer" or not.

Comment: See my changes to the answer.

Comment: i have no idea whats wrong with me but when i press add button i can add textboxes but they are just html textboxes. i mean they are <input name="txtOther0" type="text" id="txtOther0" /> . and when i try to run your code exception handled and kick me out of the foreach loop. i guess inputs are not have server tag.if this is the problem how can i make them runat="server" ?